# Sencha Touch Ext.picker setData not working correctly

Tags: extjs

I have been trying to figure out why I am not able to update the Sencha Touch  picker  data field (see the code at the end of post) using setData method. I created an array called slotsdata where I defined my data. The data look exactly like this:

```
{text: '50 KB/s', value: 50},  
         {text: '100 KB/s', value: 100},  
         {text: '200 KB/s', value: 200},  
         {text: '300 KB/s', value: 300}
```

1. When I tried to set the data using setData()
   picker.setData(slotsdata);
   No error are displayed but picker does not display any data.
2. When I tried to update the data like this:

   `slots: [

   {

                       name : 'picker_slot1',

                       title: 'slot1',

                       data: [slotsdata]

                   }

               ]`
   It does not work. No errors in the console. The picker is empty.
3. The only way I can update is using this syntax:

   `slots: [

                   {

                       name : 'picker_slot1',

                       title: 'slot1',

                       data: slotsdata

                   }

               ]`

I would like to be able to update my picker data using method #1. Can anyone help me with this issue. Any help will be appreciated.

This is the code:

```
myFunction: function(){  
var data = this.getData();  
var slotsdata = [];  
var pickerData = data.dosage.split(',');  
for( var i = 0; i < pickerData.length; i++ ){  
    slotsdata.push({text: pickerData[i], value: pickerData[i]})  
}  
var picker = Ext.create('Ext.Picker', {  
    slots: [  
        {  
            name : 'picker_slot1',  
            title: 'slot1',  
            data: slotsdata  
        }  
    ]  
});  
//this does not work  
//picker.setData(slotsdata);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setSlots()` method of picker class like:

```
picker.setSlots({
    name: 'limit_speed',
    title: 'Speed',
    data: [
        { text: '50 KB/s', value: 50 },
        { text: '100 KB/s', value: 100 }
    ]
});
```